# How to copy file from local system to kubernetes pods with new kubectl version

Tags: kubernetes, sdk, cloud, kubectl

I'm trying to copy files from my local to kubernetes pods. I've been using the command for a very few months now and everything worked fine:

```
kubectl cp C:/test.jar backend-0:/usr/local/myproject/tomcat/webapps/WEB-INF/lib -c tomcat
```

Now I bought a new computer, re-configured the development environment, and now when I try to use the same command, I see an error:

```
error: one of src or dest must be a local file specification
```

I'm using Google Cloud SDK as a terminal. The old computer had the **Google Cloud SDK** version **368.0.0**, now it's **396.0.0**. Also, **kubectl** version changed, was **1.16.6** now it's **1.22.12**.

Please tell me which command in the terminal will be relevant now, how should I use copying? Thanks!

Comment: try replacing  `/usr/local/myproject/tomcat/webapps/WEB-INF/lib` with `/tmp` and check if its working ?

Comment: No, the same message

Comment: Your command is right, not reproducible on kubernetes 1.24.3 and Linux client.

Comment: Would it make more sense to create a custom Docker image that already contains Tomcat and your application jar file?  Right now you'd have to repeat this `kubectl cp` command for every replica of your deployment, and repeat it again if the pods are ever destroyed and recreated (including if a node fails outside your control or if a node has excessive resource utilization).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use absolute paths like `C:/test.jar`

You can try the following:

1. Make sure you are under `c:/`
2. Execute:
   `kubectl cp test.jar backend-0:/usr/local/myproject/tomcat/webapps/WEB-INF/lib -c tomcat`

Comment: Yes, it helped, thank you! To tell the truth, the command also works with C:/ on some machines, if you encounter this, see the solution above